# Creating a unique index for an entire row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a unique index that prevents entry into the database that has the same row. Some of the columns will have the same data but if the entire row matches I want to prevent it from entering the Db.

I have tried the below query. Am I right tho in thinking that this will prevent entry to the db if any of the col values are already in a row in the database.

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX MyUnique_Index
     ON myDbTable (Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4, Col_5, Col_6, Col_7);
```

I think the current index is preventing any new entry if any of the columns in the unique index match and not all columns together.

Comment: You are on the right path. Honestly what you should do is create a sample table and test

Comment: This will prevent multiple inserts assuming none of the columns are `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your unique index will prevent duplicates on the *combination* of the seven columns.

But I can think of three caveats:

1. MySQL allows multiple rows that match, where the columns are `NULL`.  This applies if *any* of the columns are `NULL`.
2. Only the first 767 bytes of each column are used for the index (this might vary by storage engine).
3. Depending on the storage engine, there are limits on the total number of bytes in all keys or the number of columns in the index.